# Ошибка с импортом изображения в React

Tags: html, reactjs

Не могу понять в чем проблема, вроде все правильно импортирую, но какая-то ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Вы импортируете изображение как файл и вставляете его в место где должно быть ссылка.

Указывайте расположение изображения, ничего импортировать не нужно: `<img src="images/logo.png" />`

Comment: Я так и делаю, но изображение не отображается на странице

Comment: @Protmir нет вы так не делаете.